# Botón condicional link javascript

Tags: javascript, botón, enlace

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer un botón condicional con javascript, el cual tiene una función en "onclick", y dependiendo del resultado de la función, te mande a un link diferente.

Es decir, quiero hacer un botón que funcione como link, pero que tenga varias condiciones, y dependiendo de estas condiciones, diferentes links.

La condición es que si el resultado da un array diferente, te redireccione a un html distinto. Por ejemplo,

```
if (resultado == [0,0,0]){
   window.location="url1"
} else if (resultado == [1,1,1]){
   window.location="url2"
}
```

etc... con hasta 16 condiciones (lo que también he pensado hacerlo con switch, pero no me sale de ninguna forma...)

Si alguien puede orientarme cómo puedo hacerlo le estaría muy agradecida.

Answer (score 1):

En la línea de lo que comenta [@alanfcm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/275152/128321) y para evitarte ifElses o switchCases te propongo lo siguiente.

Puedes crearte un objeto con cada uno de los arrays (convertidos a cadena) como clave y como valor el enlace que se corresponda, algo así:

```js
const urls = {
    "[1,1,1]": "http://miurl1.ext",
    "[1,1,0]": "http://miurl2.ext"
    // ...
}
```

y en tu función hacer lo siguiente:

```js
    window.location.href = urls[JSON.stringify(resultado)];
```

Te dejo un ejemplo por aquí:

```js
const urls = {
  "[0,0,0]": "https://es.stackoverflow.com",
  "[0,0,1]": "https://twitter.com",
  "[0,1,0]": "https://facebook.com",
  "[1,1,0]": "https://linkedin.com",
  "[1,0,0]": "https://google.com",
  "[0,1,1]": "https://duckduckgo.com",
  "[1,0,1]": "https://bing.com",
  "[1,1,1]": "https://apple.com",
 }

function goToLink(element) {
  const result = JSON.parse(element.dataset.value); // convertimos el valor a Array para emular el comportamiento descrito
  window.location.href = urls[JSON.stringify(result)];
};
```

```html
<button data-value="[0,0,0]" onclick="goToLink(this)">Stackoverflow en Español</button>
<button data-value="[0,0,1]" onclick="goToLink(this)">Twitter</button>
<button data-value="[0,1,0]" onclick="goToLink(this)">FaceBook</button>
<button data-value="[1,1,0]" onclick="goToLink(this)">LinkedIn</button>
<button data-value="[1,0,0]" onclick="goToLink(this)">Google</button>
<button data-value="[0,1,1]" onclick="goToLink(this)">DuckDuckGo</button>
<button data-value="[1,0,1]" onclick="goToLink(this)">Bing</button>
<button data-value="[1,1,1]" onclick="goToLink(this)">Apple</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `JSON.stringify()` asi:

```js
var resultado = [1,1,1];

if (JSON.stringify(resultado) == JSON.stringify([0,0,0])){
  console.log("url1")
} else if (JSON.stringify(resultado) == JSON.stringify([1,1,1])){
   console.log("url2")
}
```